# Why Kotlin coroutines run in the same thread sequentially?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I thought that calling a "suspend" function from coroutine context using `launch` makes the call asynchronous. But in the example below I see that 2 invocations of `placeOrder` method are not running in the same thread one after another.
What is my mistake?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import java.io.File

fun main() = runBlocking {
    t("1")
    launch {
        t("2")
        placeOrder("C:\\Users")
        t("3")
    }
    launch {
        t("12")
        placeOrder("C:\\Program Files")
        t("13")
    }
    t("4")
}


fun t(s: String) {
    val currentThread = Thread.currentThread()
    println(s + ": " + currentThread.name + " " +     currentThread.id)
}

suspend fun placeOrder(d:String): String {
    t("placeOrder $d")
    val user = createUser(d) // asynchronous call to user service
    val order = createOrder(user) // asynchronous call to order service
    t("placeOrder $d finished")
    return order
}

suspend fun createUser(d:String): String {
    t("createUser $d")
    val toString = File(d).walk().map {
        it.length()
    }.sum().toString()
    t("createUser $d finished")
    return toString
}

suspend fun createOrder(user: String): String {
    t("createOrder $user")
    val toString = File("C:\\User").walk().map {
        it.length()
    }.sum().toString()
    t("createOrder $user finished")
    return toString
}
```

Output:

```
1: main 1
4: main 1
2: main 1
placeOrder C:\Users: main 1
createUser C:\Users: main 1
createUser C:\Users finished: main 1
createOrder 1094020270277: main 1
createOrder 1094020270277 finished: main 1
placeOrder C:\Users finished: main 1
3: main 1
12: main 1
placeOrder C:\Program Files: main 1
createUser C:\Program Files: main 1
createUser C:\Program Files finished: main 1
createOrder 5651227104: main 1
createOrder 5651227104 finished: main 1
placeOrder C:\Program Files finished: main 1
13: main 1
```

Comment: Aren't you using two launch{} calls ?

Comment: @StavroXhardha Yes, I thought that I can launch in this way 2 parallel executions, but it does not work this way. Added output to the question

Comment: Can you add the output of the `prinrln` statements?

Comment: @JohnMercier added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing suspendable IO, you wrote blocking IO:

```
File(d).walk().map {
    it.length()
}
```

Your functions never actually suspend and instead they block the single thread associated with their `runBlocking` dispatcher.

You gave your coroutines no opportunity to execute concurrently.

If you applied `withContext(IO) { ... }` around the above code, you'd get concurrency, but of the plain-old Java type, several threads being blocked in IO operations together.

Comment: What are examples of suspendable I/O?

Comment: For file IO, i don't have any examples. File IO is blocking even at the low OS level. For network IO, using any async API that allows you to submit a callback that gets the result of the request.

Comment: I'm using Vertx, and they have an http client with callback. But how such coroutine will look like if the next coroutine needs it result to run?

Comment: You implement each network call as a suspending function by following [this simple idiom](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#wrapping-callbacks). After that it becomes trivial to compose them --- just call them as regular functions and pass the result of one to the next one.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this behavior is twofold:

1. All your coroutines are executed in the `runBlocking` scope, which is a single-threaded event loop. So this means only a single thread is ever used unless a different context is specified. (`launch(Dispatchers.IO)` as an example)
2. Even then it would be possible for the coroutines to interleave, except your coroutines do call suspending functions which actually have to suspend. This means it is effectively a normal sequential function call. If your functions included a `yield()` or `delay(..)` call you would see the coroutines interleave in execution.

Comment: So what is the right approach to write a suspendable method, which does I/O or JDBC ot something like this?

Comment: By its nature you need to build it on an asynchronous API which does some work, then send you a message when the work is done so you can resume your own code. JDBC by its very nature cannot be suspendable (seems ADBA is the async replacement) while an API built on `java.nio.channels.*` would work for the file operations.

Answer (score 1):

***launch*** function signature:

```
fun CoroutineScope.launch(
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit
): Job (source)
```

As per the official Kotlin documentation [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html):

```
When launch { ... } is used without parameters, it inherits the context (and
thus dispatcher) from the CoroutineScope it is being launched from.
```

In your case, it inherits the context of the main runBlocking coroutine which runs in the main thread.
As coroutine context includes a coroutine dispatcher that determines what thread or threads the corresponding coroutine uses for its execution, so you can provide a different CoroutineContext with your *launch* coroutine builder. For Example:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    t("1")
    launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        t("2")
        placeOrder("C:\\Users")
        t("3")
    }
    launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        t("12")
        placeOrder("C:\\Program Files")
        t("13")
    }
    t("4")
}
```

Regarding suspend functions, a suspending function is just a regular Kotlin function with an additional suspend modifier which indicates that the function can suspend the execution of a coroutine. It doesn't make the call asynchronous by default.
You can execute your function code with custom dispatcher(e.g. IO dispatcher) using Kotlin's withContext() function as below:

```
suspend fun get(url: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){/* Code for N/W logic */}
```

This will execute the body of the function in separate Thread than the calling coroutine context.

Here is 3-part series blog explaining usage of coroutines in Android apps :
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-i-getting-the-background-3e0e54d20bb

Answer (score 1):

replace `launch` with `async`

[read this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the code above is running **synchronously** even without `runBlocking`!

Since all the coroutines are launched into the **main** running on a **single** thread, ultimately you can use **IO** dispatcher which uses **multiple** threads.

Also, note that **multiple** coroutines can run on a **single** thread but they are never executed in parallel, they may appear as running in parallel because of thread switching from one coroutine to another when a new coroutine is **launched** or **suspended**.